# Remove specific fragment from the backstack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my app, i have 4 buttons, these buttons will create and replace fragment then added it to the backstack.
So for example :

```
[A] -> [B] -> [C] -> [D]
```

First fragment `A` is exist, when i click at button `B`, fragment `A` will be replaced with fragment `B` and added fragment `B` to the backstack, when i click at button `C`, fragment `B` will be replaced with fragment `C` and added fragment `C` to the backstack, and so on.

My question is, when button `A` is clicked again, it will removes fragment `A` from previous backstack and added it to the last stack, so the image will looks like this:

```
[B] -> [C] -> [D] -> [A]
```

Or if i click at button `B`, the image will looks like this:

```
[A] -> [C] -> [D] -> [B]
```

How do i do it? i have try using `FragmentManager.popBackStack(indexStack, 0)`, `FragmentManager.popBackStack(Tag, 0)` but none of these work.

Answer (score 2):

Remove Specific fragment from the backstack using `FragmentManager`

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
trans.remove(YourSpecificFragmentHere);
trans.commit();
manager.popBackStack();
```

Answer (score 1):

try with `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE`

```
FragmentManager.popBackStack(Tag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

it should woks

Answer (score 0):

Try remove your fragment from backstack and then add it again in different transactions :

```
FragmentA fragmentA = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG_OF_FRAGMENT_A");
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragmentA).commit();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerResId, fragmentA ).commit();
```